Jolt spec for subtracting 1 minus array elements
JSON input:
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "example",
  "value1": [0.67, 0.78, 0.245],
  "value2": [0.45, 0.55, 0.65],
  "value3": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
  "otherField": "some data"
}

JSON output
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "example",
  "value1": [0.33, 0.22, 0.755],
  "value2": [0.55, 0.45, 0.35],
  "value3": [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
  "otherField": "some data"
}

I want jolt spec for the above transformations 1 - array elements
Note that the number of the elements within the value arrays may vary

And also I donot know exactly how many elements present in arrays so I want to use dynamically

You can try the following spec:
[
  {//This is to Subtract
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "value*": {
        "*": "=doubleSubtract(1.0,@(0))"
      }
    }
  },
  {//This is to Round by 3 digit at most
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "value*": {
        "*": "=divideAndRound(3,@(0),1.0)"
      }
    }
  }
]

I hope it works.

Thanks Barbaros. Still I have long way to catchup with the master ;)
